# Same modal for creating and updating records on Angular (angular + bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that creates objects on a simple CRUD.
I wanted to reuse the same modal to Edit/Update records since the form is the same.

I have a ng-repeat directive to lay out the different object on bootstrap panels.

The problem is that when I click edit, the form gains the scope of the current object to edit but when I exit the form and click Add New, the same modal pops up with the scope of the previous object.
If I try to $scope.object = '', the two way data binding kicks in and it updates my model and resets the object values.

How can I reset the scope without resetting the object I previously edited?

Thanks

Comment: Is your modal written as an AngularJS Directive?

Comment: No, it's a normal modal written with bootstrap.

Comment: please provide samples of code, what you've tried, and where your issues are. a jsFiddle or Plunker wouldn't hurt.

Comment: A possible solution is when you click Add New, add an object to the end of the repeater and have it gain the scope of the newly added object. This way if you have a Cancel button, you can just remove the last item added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, the answer was creating instances of the modal everytime I want to add or edit a request.